# Is there a 'proper' way to extract Open Graph meta data in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, tags

I want to use Open Graph metadata from websites for my **scraper** .

I know I can use `get_meta_tags()` for regular metadata, but I didn't find anything similar for og tags.

I can parse it manually or use some external tool from github but is there any 'proper' way to do it? Any library that is considered default? Especially for Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is [fusonic/opengraph](https://github.com/fusonic/opengraph). Since it uses guzzle, and some symphony components. Although, as with most under-used PHP projects, check out a fork for updated dependencies, such as [benallfree/opengraph](https://github.com/benallfree/opengraph).

You can add it via composer using require with a git url:

```
{
  "require": {
    "fusonic/opengraph": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/benallfree/opengraph.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a below code to get all links from text content and download open graph informations from website

to get tags:

```
  public function getOG($txt,$name)
  {
      $start = strpos($txt, "property=\"$name\"");
      
      if(is_numeric($start))
      {
            $end   = strpos($txt, ">", $start);
            if(is_numeric($end))
            {
                $len = strlen("property=\"$name\"");
                
                $substr = substr($txt, $start + $len  , $end-$start + $len);
                
                $exp = explode('"', $substr);
                $f = $exp[1] ?? '';
                return $f;
            }
      }            
      
      return "";
  }
```

and to get array of links:

```
  public function getLinks($string)
  {
      try{
        
             $explode = explode("http", $string);                          
          
             $links = array();
             $x = -1;
             
             $kodowanie = 'UTF-8';
             
             foreach($explode as $ix => $link)
             {
                 $substr = substr($link, 0,3);
                 
                 if($substr == 's:/') //https
                 {
                    $e = explode(' ', $link);
                    $x++;
                    $links[$x]['link'] = 'http'.$e[0];                    
                 }
                 
                  if($substr == '://') //http
                 {
                    $e = explode(' ', $link);
                    $x++;
                    $links[$x]['link'] = 'http'.$e[0];                    
                 } 
                 
                 if($x < 0) continue; 
                 
                 $c = strlen($links[$x]['link']);
                 $lastChar = $links[$x]['link'][$c-1];
                 
                 if($lastChar == '.' || $lastChar == ',')
                 {
                    $links[$x]['link'] = substr($links[$x]['link'], 0, $c-1);
                 }
                 
                 $exenter = explode("\n", $links[$x]['link']);
                 $links[$x]['link'] = $exenter[0];
                 
                 $exspacja = explode(" ", $links[$x]['link']);
                 $links[$x]['link'] = $exspacja[0];
                 
                                  
               
                 
                 //Get open graph info
                 $html = @file_get_contents($links[$x]['link']);
                 if($html != null)
                 {
                     $kodowanie = $this->getCharset($html);
                   
                     
                     $title = $this->getOG($html, 'og:title');
                     $desc = $this->getOG($html, 'og:description');
                     $img = $this->getOG($html, 'og:image');
                     
                     
                     $links[$x]['og']['og:title'] = $title;                              
                     $links[$x]['og']['og:description'] = $desc;                              
                     $links[$x]['og']['og:image'] = $img;    
                     
               
                                  if(!is_numeric(strpos($img, 'http')))
                                  {
                                       
                                           $eL = explode('/', $links[$x]['link']);           
                                           $domain = $eL[0].'//'.$eL[2];
                                           
                                           if(substr($img, 0,1) == '/')
                                           {
                                                $img = $domain.$img;   
                                           }else
                                           $img = $domain.'/'.$img;   
                                           
                                         $links[$x]['og']['og:image'] = $img;                                                
                                  }
                                                                                                       
                                  $file = @file_get_contents($img); 
                                  if($file != null)
                                  {
                                    $links[$x]['og']['b64'] = base64_encode($file);
                                  }                                             
                 }
                 
                 //$links[$x]['link'] = '1';
                 
             }
             
             $readyLinks = array();
             
             if($kodowanie != 'UTF-8' && $kodowanie != 'UTF8')
             {
                 foreach($links as $x => $item)
                 {
                     $readyLinks[$x] = $item;
                     $readyLinks[$x]['og']['og:title'] =   \mb_convert_encoding($item['og']['og:title'],  'UTF-8', $kodowanie);   
                     $readyLinks[$x]['og']['og:description'] =  \mb_convert_encoding($item['og']['og:description'],  'UTF-8', $kodowanie);   
                 }
                 
                 $links = $readyLinks;
             }
             
          
             return $links;
             
        }catch(\app\library\_PajaxException $ex) 
        {
          throw $ex;         
        }catch(\Throwable $thr) { throw new \app\library\_PajaxException($thr, \app\library\_PajaxException::THROWABLE, $this->getEnv()); }
  }
```